# working on a file from outside the directory

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, directory

I'm trying to create a .info file for eact .prt file.

but I need to do ir from a different directory, and it will need to point to a new directory each time.

so far I have

```
#!/bin/bash
DP_DATE= cat /tmp/dp_date.txt
FOLDER= "/transfer/report_archive/preprod/$DP_DATE/"

for f in $FOLDER
do
for file in *.prt
do 
    [ -f ".info.$file" ] || wc -c < "$file" >> ".info.$file"
done
done
```

I'm not sure if this can work at all!

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It's not clear why you're looping over `$FOLDER` - does dp_date.txt contain multiple dates, or do you want to loop through the directories *inside* `$FOLDER`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have space after `=` in an assignment. And to assign the output of a command, you have to wrap it with `$(...)` or backticks.

To deal with the files being in another directory, the simplest way is to `cd` to the directory before processing it. I do it in a subshell inside the loop, so that before the next directory is processed it will return to the original directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
DP_DATE=$(cat /tmp/dp_date.txt)
FOLDER="/transfer/report_archive/preprod/$DP_DATE/"

for f in $FOLDER
do ( # Subshell so cd is temporary
    cd "$f"
    for file in *.prt
    do 
        [ -f ".info.$file" ] || wc -c < "$file" >> ".info.$file"
    done
   )
done
```

Comment: bamar this is unbelievable, thank you so much, yep. dp_date is a temp file that will be update each day,these reports go into a new folder for each date.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap command substitutions in `$(` and `)`:

```
DP_DATE=$(cat /tmp/dp_date.txt)
```

Spaces after the equals sign will result in an empty variable and trying to execute the second parameter:

```
FOLDER="/transfer/report_archive/preprod/$DP_DATE/"
```